# How to get the BPM once FFT and peak detection has been performed

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft

I have performed an FFT of a wav file, plotted a graph of this, and have used peak utils to get the peaks and printed these out one after the other.

How do I go from here to getting the songs BPMs (beats per minute)?

Do I need to perform an IFFT? As I am assuming I need to get back to a time context. Or is there another way to get back to a time context?

I'm not after any code, I just want a push in the right direction of the next step.

Comment: @Vorsprung If this is the answer, you should probably, you know, make it an answer. =)

Comment: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/detecting-drum-bpm-in-a-noisy-wav-file

Comment: Thank you for your link, however I am still not sure what to do next, was your answer supposed to point me to the "Then calculate the time domain envelope of the signal ("lossy peak" is the easiest way to do this) with a time constant that's roughly matched to the length of the drum beats." bit? How do I calculate the time domain envelope of the signal? I have already detected and found the peaks so do I need "lossy peak"?

Comment: BPM can not be measured reliably by using FFT peak detection.  Instead, start reading the many many academic papers on Audio Tempo Estimation on MIREX: http://www.music-ir.org/mirex/wiki/MIREX_HOME

Comment: Well im currently learning about FFT so it has to be FFT whether it is reliable or not

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but here goes; what unit are the values in the array that is returned by peakutils.peak.indexes(y, thres=0.3, min_dist=1), in?

Answer (score 1):

<s>Measure the peak to peak distance in seconds and divide 60 by that number. For instance 0.5 seconds peak to peak = 60/0.5 = 120 bpm. This will work to some extent on regular dance music but on other types will be not so good</s>

Sorry I completely misunderstood your question.  The above is how to do it on a wave form like you'd see in audacity.

With an FFT as it is in frequency domain.   Look for peaks in the lower frequency range.  If the music is in the range of 60 to 180 bpm then this corresponds to frequencies of 1 to 3 Hz.  So look for peaks in this frequency range

To convert the frequency of the peak to bpm multiply by 60.  So 2 Hz * 60 = 120 bpm

Comment: Thank you Vorsprung for your reply, to measure the peak to peak distance in seconds, do I need to perform an IFFT? or are there still time values available from the FFT data?

Comment: Oh lol yeah wav not wave. Ok thank you, I already have the peaks, how do I then calculate the BPM from these peaks?

Comment: ok thank you, but what do you do when you have more than one peak, do you take the average of them and then multiply that by 60 to get the BPM (average)?

Comment: The following are some frequenices of my peaks: 232 Hz, 442 Hz, 493 Hz, etc, but it isn't a fast song, so is it really as simple as multiplying these values (or perhaps the average of them) by 60? As the resulting BPM i am getting is far too extreme to be correct

Comment: I agree that 232Hz is not an artifact of the bpm!  I have been reading a few things about this (i am not a maths genius) and it seems that fft is not good at detecting frequencies over a large range.  This article http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3580/most-efficient-way-to-extract-frequency-components-of-audio-signal-with-near-hum is talking about pitch detection not bpm but has some interesting thoughts about it.  You may need to alter the parameters on your fft.